# I created an app with facebook audience but I am not sure about google play URL if I do not have live app in playstore do facebook approve or not

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter and facebook audience.  I created an app with facebook audience but I am not sure about google play URL if I do not have live app in playstore do facebook approve or not. But if I want to live app in playstore .What do I have to write some code in my app ? Thanks for the help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic190.jpg)

Comment: well according to the docs and as much I know you need to have a live app on play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook audience will show test ads even if the App is not uploaded but Facebook will only Approve the App(so that you can start earning) if the App is live on Playstore